# make printfn more clear in a function pipeline

Tags: f#

So I have this last piece in a pipe

```
|> Array.iter (fun name -> name 
                                |> transform 
                                |> printfn "RENAME '%s' INTO '%s'" name )
```

The transform is:

```
let transform (text: string) = 
    text.Replace(" ", ".")
```

To me the `iter` predicate function isn't very clear, it is saying push name into `transform` then push the result in `printfn` with the original name appended to it....

Is there a way to make the transformation pipe more intention revealing using pipe forward or backward operators.

I thought maybe

```
name
  |> printfn "RENAME '%S' INTO '%S'"
  <| transform
```

But obviously that doesn't work.

If it can't look nicer in the pipe then I guess it is the most succinct way - apart from making a a new function that combines the printfn in some fashion with the transform, but I wouldn't mind avoiding that...

I just want to make sure I'm not missing any straightforward syntax..

I don't think there is, because I'm facing a function that takes multiple arguments, in order to use it in a pipe forward it can only have 1 parameter, which is effectively what I'm doing by partial application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes it is better to avoid unnecessary piping as it can obfuscate the code.
Your function simply prints as follows:

```
printfn "RENAME '%s' INTO '%s'" name (transform name)
```

And you can omit parens by using `<|`:

```
printfn "RENAME '%s' INTO '%s'" name <| transform name
```

And that looks better IMHO.

Comment: so would that last expression be next to the `Array.iter` then

Comment: `Array.iter (fun name ->` and the body, yes

Answer (score 2):

Maybe skipping the pipe is more clear in this case?

```
|> Array.iter (fun name -> printfn "RENAME '%s' INTO '%s'" name (transform name))
```

Also note that your original predicate can be composed further like so:

```
|> Array.iter (transform >> printfn "RENAME '%s' INTO '%s'" name)
```

Which can be written like this if you want the transform to come last:

```
|> Array.iter ((printfn "RENAME '%s' INTO '%s'" name) << transform)
```

Comment: There we go, that last expression looks pretty good. Obviously there was something I'm missing

Comment: The last two (the composition ones) are incorrect as `name` doesn't exist in context (the `fun name ->` part is missing. which leads to the fact that composition can't be used there (as-is) as the argument is needed more than once

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of how I would go about this task:

```
let array = [|
    "one"
    "two"
    "three"
|]


let transform s = s, s + "_transformed"

let printIt (n,t) =  printfn "RENAME '%s' INTO '%s'" n t 


array
|> Array.map transform
|> Array.iter printIt
```

My "best practice" tells me that I always should create and use functions. This way the flow (map and iter) is constant, and the functions or data may change.

**Addendum to "clarify" WHY to use functions and what not**

```
let myPipeLineWithPrint t p a=
    a
    |> Array.map t
    |> Array.iter p

//"Old" Version With above data
myPipeLineWithPrint transform printIt array


type SomeRecord = {
    Name: string
    MoreStuff: string
}

type OtherRecord = {
    NewName: string
    OldName: string
}


let array2 = [|
    {Name="one"; MoreStuff="dontcare"}
    {Name="two"; MoreStuff="dontcare"}
    {Name="three"; MoreStuff="dontcare"}
|] 

let transform2 {Name=n; MoreStuff=ms} = transform n

myPipeLineWithPrint transform2 printIt array2


let transform3 {Name=n; MoreStuff=_} =
    let (_,nn) = transform n
    {NewName= nn; OldName=n}

let printIt2 {NewName=nn; OldName = o} = printfn "RENAME '%s' INTO '%s'" o nn   

myPipeLineWithPrint transform3 printIt2 array2
```

Comment: I appreciate the time taken to provide this answer, however, I'm struggling to see what this answers from my question. Could you elaborate it a bit more, for example `s, s + "_transformed"` what does this do?

Comment: I've run it, and it does give the desired output, however I do feel this is a little to abstracted, I did mention that you could do this via refactoring out to a function, but I wanted to try and keep `printfn` inline with the pipeline, if that makes sense?

Comment: @CallumLinington The point is that this might be simple now. If you want to change stuff at some time later on, and change how the data are defined or are handled during the pipeline or how its printed, it might be that you have several places for printing even, its a good thing to be ahead and actually have functions. Most probably the pipeline is ok, but what data are going through it, and how that data is printed is in fact changeing.

Comment: Yeah, I kind of pre guarded my question with (a probably poor explanation) of the fact I kind of wanted to steer away from those kind of reuse, mainly because I'm focusing purely on the language operators and syntax first.

Comment: @CallumLinington Ive updated my answer to try to make it clearer how/what/why/where... Hope it helps at least ;-)